# Identifying subject and object of wh- non question

Tags: grammar, subjects, objects

So I have this sentence `What the feeling of the student is.` But I'm a bit confused when identifying the subject and object of this sentence. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as the definition/explanation and examples on dictionary or other trusted reference.

Comment: The sentence is either ungrammatical or embedded. That kind of clause cannot be a stand-alone sentence. It needs to be part of a larger sentence: "I don't know what the feeling of the student is".

Comment: It's a subordinate clause that is part of a larger construction. More specifically, it's probably an interrogative clause (embedded question). The subject is "the feeling", but there is no object -- "what" is predicative complement of "is".